# How to move a script into a div container

Tags: javascript, html, elementor

So im working on a website for a client and want to move a script that i've built in codepen into a div container in html elementor, everytime i add it into the website (elementor) it places the window at the bottom of the page and not into the container.

*Update*

Trying to move JS into a Div container to add to specific part of website, would a `document.getElementById` work? and how should i go about it??

I've tried to add it within the web builder via wordpress but when i attach the JS via elementor, it takes the script and applies / views it on the bottom of the page under the footer, I just want the script to be viewable in a specific section.

HTML

```
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/d9f87fb1a2c5db1ea0e2feda9bd42b39b5bedc41/build/three.min.js"></script>
<!-- OrbitControls.js -->
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/d9f87fb1a2c5db1ea0e2feda9bd42b39b5bedc41/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<!-- DRACOLoader.js -->
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/d9f87fb1a2c5db1ea0e2feda9bd42b39b5bedc41/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js"></script>
<!-- GLTFLoader.js -->
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/d9f87fb1a2c5db1ea0e2feda9bd42b39b5bedc41/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  *debug* add js element to this container
  
</div>
```

JS

```
let gltf = null;
let mixer = null;
let clock = new THREE.Clock();
let controls;
let camera;

init();
animate();
  
function init() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
  let light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffcc, 20, 200 );
light.position.set( 4, 30, 80 );
scene.add( light );

let light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x20202A, 20, 100 );
light2.position.set( 30, -10, 30 );
scene.add( light2 );

  
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, width / height, 0.01, 10000 );
    camera.position.set(0, 3, 10);

    let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 5, 100);
    let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: "#707070"
    });
    
 
    let manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
        console.log( item, loaded, total );
    };

    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin( 'anonymous' ); 
    loader.setDRACOLoader( new THREE.DRACOLoader() );
    
    let scale = 0.01;
    let url = "https://8ad.studio/wp-content/uploads/3D%20Assets/8AD_LOGO.gltf";
    
    loader.load(url, function (data) {
        gltf = data;
        let object = gltf.scene;
        object.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
        //object.position.y = -5;
        //object.position.x = 4;
        object.castShadow = true;
        object.receiveShadow = true;

        let animations = gltf.animations;
        if ( animations && animations.length ) {
            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
            for ( let i = 0; i < animations.length; i ++ ) {
                let animation = animations[ i ];
                mixer.clipAction( animation ).play();
            }
        }
        scene.add(object);
    });

    

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.rotateSpeed = 0.3;
controls.zoomSpeed = 0.9;

controls.minDistance = 12;
controls.maxDistance = 12;

controls.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI /2; // radians

controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    if (mixer) mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
    controls.update();
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Could you give us a code example of this? It's hard to figure out the problem without a clear example of what's going on.

Comment: yes, here is the codepen to it.
https://codepen.io/8AD/pen/wvgYvbj

Comment: document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); Do you want to change this line to put the domElement into the correct div?

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to make the threejs canvas appear inside a div, you have to change where the canvas appears in the DOM. This is done in Threejs using the renderer.domElement

```
// change this:
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
// to this:
document.getElementById('container').appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Check [my codepen](https://codepen.io/sean-b765/pen/BapqyxM) for an example. Traditionally this might be used if you're showing a 3d model of a product to customers, and you want to embed the canvas in a container in the DOM. But now the position of your models are out of whack. You'll just need to configure the camera position/zoom

Comment: Wow, you literally just saved my entire project <3,
Thank you, Cheers!! :D